# Can not run any application after a while

Tags: windows-7, virus

The question title may seem nonsense but it is true. When I start my pc, I can use it for a while. Then, it starts to get behave nonsense. I can not run any application, browse on internet or simply can not do anything. However, I can continue using already opened applications. For example, if the notepad is already in use, I can save a text file or open a new file using notepad. Moreover, when it starts behaves like that, I can not shut down my computer or restart it. The only solution becomes to force it shut down by holding shut down button until it powers down. When I start it again, everything is fine as usual.

This problem has been started like months ago. However, in the beginning it was not that much serious, it was happening only once in 2 weeks or more. Now, it is started to happen on every day more than once. This problem is really annoying. My suspicion is that there may be some kind of virus. Because, as I said, I can not understand when it is going to start. By the way I am using Windows 7. I do not want to reinstall OS since I have worked a lot to setup my current configuration.

I tried several solutions. One of them has worked for a while. The problem has gone away for 1-2 weeks. Then, it started again. The solution that I tried is below.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2688326

EDIT: Due to my experience with anti-virus programs, they are not very good detecting viruses which are already infected. Instead, they provide protection against viruses. Therefore, if anyone knows any tool which is good in detecting already infected viruses, I may try it as well.

Comment: Do you have any kind of anti-virus installed? Have you acted at all on your suspicions?

Comment: Try boot scan using any antivirus and also do run checkdsk for drives and check its integrity. Is that you are getting any error registered in eventvwr and proceed further

Comment: I am using Avast I tried full scan with it but nothing has been found @Kaizerwolf

Comment: I have tried boot scan as well. The problem is that I am not getting any error. It is driving me crazy. It is not deterministic and you can not know when it is going to happen. Really interesting problem @vembutech

Answer (score 0):

A good antivirus installed is the normal solution for this.
You can try this also - https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/delete-all-event-logs-at-once-in-windows-7-378338/ - , if you still want to remain in the current state and does not count the antivirus installation also.

Comment: Are you sure that deleting all event logs at once is safe?

Comment: How does deleting all event logs solve this issue?